# Python dictionary update doesn't work inside for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a method `get_h1()` that returns 2 tags:

```
[<h2>Запись к врачу</h2>, <h2>Запись на диагностику</h2>]
```

I have another method that has a for loop inside. It should get both tags from the `get_h1()` method and add 3 values in dictionary. But in result it returns values only for 1 tag

```
def print_h1(self):
        self.h1 = {}
        self.h1_all = self.get_h1()
        self.h1_all = [self.h.text for self.h in self.h1_all]
        for self.h in self.h1_all:
            self.value = self.h
            self.leng = len(self.h)
            if self.key in self.h:
                self.key = "YES"
            else: 
                self.key = "NO"
            self.h1.update({'value':self.value, 'leng': self.leng, 'key': self.key})
        return self.h1
```

Here is the result:

```
{'value': 'Запись на диагностику', 'leng': 21, 'key': 'NO'}
```

How can I get the result for both tags?

Comment: You'll have to use something other than a dictionary, e.g. a list, so the result could be: `[{'value': '...', ...}, {'value': '...', ...}]`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

> `dict.update([other])`
>
> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, *overwriting existing keys*.

You have *one* `self.h1` dictionary, and each call to `self.h1.update` overwrites its data. Moreover, it's impossible to put duplicate keys into dictionaries.

If you want to store data about *multiple* H1 tags, you should use *a list of dictionaries*.